# A dataframe with column entries listed in increasing order but with many repeated values: How to insert a column denoting group membership

Tags: python, pandas

Column zero of my dataframe has numeric values listed in ascending order but with many repetitions. How can I most elegantly insert column one with integer entries such that those in two consecutive rows are equal provided the corresponding numeric values listed in column zero are the same? For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_data = np.array([[2.4, 2.4, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 7.1, 7.1, 7.1, 7.1, 9.8, 9.8]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=my_data.T, columns=['value'])
```

I simply want to insert a column whose entries from top to bottom indicate "class membership" according to the five unique values. In other words, the column has values reading, from top to bottom, as 1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4

Comment: Yes, that will insert the desired column, but how can I insert code that will also determine the entries themselves, i.e. find [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4] ?

My actual dataframe will be much larger--this was just a minimum working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cat.codes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) for this -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_data = np.array([[2.4, 2.4, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 7.1, 7.1, 7.1, 7.1, 9.8, 9.8]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=my_data.T, columns=['value'])

df['class membership'] = df['value'].astype('category').cat.codes+1

>>> df
    value  class membership
0     2.4                 1
1     2.4                 1
2     3.2                 2
3     3.2                 2
4     3.2                 2
5     7.1                 3
6     7.1                 3
7     7.1                 3
8     7.1                 3
9     9.8                 4
10    9.8                 4
```